# How do I get a copy of a Pilot Operating Handbook?

Tags: aircraft-performance, propeller, poh

I need the POH for a Cassutt Plus or any variation for a University Project but I can't seem to find anything on the plane.
Any other information (flight capabilities etc) would be helpful - with references if possible!
Thanks

Comment: Hi Chloe, and welcome to Aviation.SE! Please take the [tour](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn how this site works.
 I'm afraid resource location questions are considered off-topic here so this may get closed either for that or because it is excessively broad. If you could narrow it down to the specific data you need, it would be better. Good luck with your project, and I hope you stick around.

Comment: Doubt you'll find one. Homebuilt plane like that would not have had a POH written like a factory certified plane would have.    A couple of the Cassutt planes are mentioned in this book  https://books.google.com/books?id=3_63vTcxl0IC&pg=PA162&lpg=PA162&dq=Cassutt+Plus&source=bl&ots=GWeXoKkG20&sig=ACfU3U25FyXEwe0mSpfXbd41lYEK5TPJJA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi0u_3jg4DlAhXPJt8KHS6-ChYQ6AEwB3oECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=Cassutt%20Plus&f=false with plans marketed by National Aeronautics Company, which doesn't seem to be around  under that name anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you won't find published POH documents for plans built homebuilts, as each aircraft is unique, the individual builder being the "manufacturer".  Possibly, a builder has made his own POH. Best bet is to write to the guy currently marketing the plans and selling parts, [Creighton King](https://www.cassuttaircraft.com/).

Comment: thanks for the help